# The apple developer account "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" adds Devices' UDID issues

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone, apple-developer

Add the iPhone Devices UDID in the Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section of your new Apple developer account, "STATUS" displays "Ineligible for 7 days" or "Ineligible for 14 days". What should I do?[Add images related to devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRQoe.jpg)

Comment: My account is an Apple personal developer and I have paid successfully.

Comment: I contacted Apple Support and transferred to a senior consultant who said he saw an error in the background but could not handle it at the moment and asked me to wait for 7 days as prompted

Comment: I have the same problem, but don't know why !